# Test Automation Framework

Tags: user-interface, automated-tests

I was wondering what would be a good UI to specify test cases. 
Currently we use macros with excel to specify our test cases and generate an xml out of it and export it to the script generator.

Excel is good and really flexible and allows testers to enter their test cases very quickly. 
However the xml generated is sometimes not well formed and the system has a huge learning curve.

I want to change the UI from excel to something else that would allow testers to enter test cases quickly and provide flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice TDD tool is [SLIM/FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/). It is a wiki system which allows to enter special tables and/or commands which trigger test methods. These test methods can be written in Java and .NET (other languages might be supported). Also there are various plug-ins for doing DB testing or Selenium web tests. Here is a first tutorial [video](http://vimeo.com/2456352).

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Test Link](http://blog.testlink.org/) for this sort of task.  It's an opensource php project.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out Fitnesse, which does a similar thing.  http://fitnesse.org/